# " Application manifest has either a different computed hash or no hash" error during installing my own Excel add-in

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, ms-office, excel-2010, add-in

I am publishing my Excel add-in using "Publish" option in project, that creates the publication within few clicks. Then I run setup.exe created by the Publish to install it into Excel. While I examined publishing options, I am still hitting the problem: another computer won't install the add-in; the publish only works on PC where I run compilation with the exception:

```
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Application manifest has 
either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all.  
---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: File, SMGMT_Translation.dll.manifest, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
 at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, Hash hash)
```

I appreciate an information about how I can overcome it. I use VS 2012.

Comment: Be sure not to make changes to .application file when you move to another computer. I got this when I changed a string inside it.

Comment: These are moved literally, by means of git repo.

Comment: @AskarIbragimov have you got any solution on this? Cz I had created new repo for my project and I am facing same issue.